# What does Heroku mean by app[web.1]?

Tags: ruby, heroku, rack, thin

What does Heroku mean by `app[web.1]` and by `<main>:48`?

I have a crash that happens only on Heroku and not on my computer, I'm trying to identify the precise line causing the crash. These are the logs

```
2012-10-08T21:31:49+00:00 app[web.1]: <main>:48:in `method_missing': wrong number of arguments (1 for 2) (ArgumentError)
2012-10-08T21:31:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
2012-10-08T21:31:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:137:in `start'
2012-10-08T21:31:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/server.rb:104:in `block in initialize'
2012-10-08T21:31:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
2012-10-08T21:31:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rackup:19:in `load'
2012-10-08T21:31:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/server.rb:104:in `==='
2012-10-08T21:31:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rackup:19:in `<main>'
2012-10-08T21:31:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/server.rb:102:in `initialize'
2012-10-08T21:31:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:9:in `new'
2012-10-08T21:31:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:9:in `run'
2012-10-08T21:31:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/server.rb:102:in `each'
2012-10-08T21:31:50+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-10-08T21:31:50+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-10-08T21:31:52+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET placeboxy.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Is the crash in my code or in the web server Thin or elsewhere?

**Edit** I changed the Procfile to run the server unicorn on Heroku and the crashed stopped. No error with puma either. Any ideas? Is Thin to fault?

Comment: The only thing I know is that app[web.1] refers to your dyno, if you have more than one dyno then you'll see app[web.2] etc ... And for instance if you have worker they'll appear as app[worker.1] ans so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `app[web.1]` is a tag that heroku adds to your log to mark which process is emitting the log, as all the logs are collected in a central place, you can still filter a single process and parse the process log.

The `<main>:48:` part means the file/line where the execution has been stopped because of the exception. In this case (`<main>`) it's the main script that's being run. You won't find your error there, probably. You have to search in the backtrace for the part of your code that is failing, look for something that's not an external library, nor core ruby. The backtrace you show is of no help, normally the error is much lower in the stack trace.

Comment: Thanks saverio. I've copied in the whole stack trace. I tried using the server Unicorn on Heroku and there was no crash, so maybe the crash is in Thin.